# Filter and sort array for searchBar result in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, full-text-search, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a search for my project. I need to filter variable `productTagsArray` and populate in array `allProductSearchResults`. `searchText` is what the user type in the searchBar. Here is the code I have to filter:

```
var allProductSearchResults: [[String : [String]]] = [[:]]
var productTagsArray : [[String : [String]]] = [[:]]

func filterContent(for SearchText: String){

allProductSearchResults = productTagsArray.filter({ (productTagsArray) -> Bool in
        for product in productTagsArray {
            if let tags = product.value as? [String] {

                for tag in tags {

                    let searchTextArr = SearchText.split {$0 == " "}
                    let searchX = searchTextArr.flatMap { $0.lowercased().components(separatedBy: " ")}
                    let tagLowerCase = tag.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: " ")
                    let isMatch = searchX.filter { tagLowerCase.range(of:$0) != nil }.count != 0
                    return isMatch

                }
            }

            return false
        }
        return false
    })
}
```

The above code is working just fine; however, the final result for variable `allProductSearchResults` is not sorted. I need the result to be sorted based on the number of words matched between `tag` and `searchText`. For example, if someone searches for `organic green kale`

```
searchText = "organic green kale"
```

and in productTagsArray if I have the following products:

```
productTagsArray = [["product1" : [kale]], ["product2" : [organic green kale, organic, green, kale]], ["product3" : [organic cucumber, organic, cucumber]]]
```

Once the filter is done with the code above, I want to make sure it is sorted based on the matching between searchText and the tag so it would be in this order:

```
allProductSearchResults = [["product2" : [organic green kale, organic, green, kale]], ["product1" : [organic kale, organic, kale]], ["product3" : [organic cucumber, organic, cucumber]]]
```

How can make this sorting possible?

Comment: somewhat unrelated, but is there any reason why your `productTagsArray` is an array of dictionaries instead of just a dictionary with products as keys and tags as values?

Comment: Also, you're saying "I need the result to be sorted based on the number of words matched between `tag` and `searchText`" - does that mean that each word in `searchText` is tested for a match? (because that's not what you're getting in your code that you say works fine)

Comment: Had that set up long time ago. I believe the reason for the array was because I needed them to be in order every time I use the variable; otherwise, Dictionary mess up the orders each time I use the variable.

Comment: @NewDev You are right. I not each word in searchText is being tested. I just edited my question and updated the code to reflect that. Still don't know how to do the sorting. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering, which only removes non-matching products, the idea would be to first `map` into a tuple with a count the number of matches and alongside the product, then `filter` out those with 0 matches, sort, then `map` back into the product.

```
func filterContent(for searchText: String) -> [[String : [String]]] {
   let searchTokens = searchText.split(" ")

   return productTagsArray.map { productTags -> ([String: [String]], Int) in
       
      var matches = 0
      for (_, tags) in productTags {

         for searchToken in searchTokens {

            // sum up the matches that of this search token 
            matches += tags.reduce(0, { 
               $0 + ($1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchToken) ? 1 : 0) })
         }

      }

      return (productTags, matches) // <-- return product with # of matches
   }
   .filter({ $0.1 > 0 }) // <-- filter out zero matches
   .sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1 }) // <-- sort by matches
   .map { $0.0 } // <-- map back to productTags

}
```